# What is the difference between QGIS for Windows and QGIS for Android?

Tags: qgis, android, windows

What is the difference between QGIS for Windows and QGIS for Android?

Is the functionality the same?

Comment: Have been using both, performance is slower on the Tablet (I expected that) but works with local files and database tables and web sources okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android there are still many limitations. For example you can't get the newest Plugins and the GUI is difficult to use as well. Generally the plugins and tools that comes with it has limitations as well. Some good people are working on it. I personally will love to have a functional Android on my Nexus while I'm on the move.